# Publications with Relations - Meteor

Tags: meteor

I recently added the lepozepo:publish-with-relations package to my project and I am trying to publish a shopping cart

```
Meteor.publish "cart", (ops={}) ->
if ops.cotizacion and not _.isEmpty ops.cotizacion
    @relations
        collection:Cotizaciones
        filter:
            _id:ops.cotizacion
            status:"new"
        mappings:[
            {
                key:"cotizacion"
                collection:CotDetails
                options:
                    limit:25
                mappings:[
                    {
                        foreign_key:"codigo"
                        collection:Productos
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]

@ready()
```

my subscription is the following

```
   Template.CotIzq.onCreated ->
     self = this
     self.autorun ->
      self.subscribe 'cart'
```

If I add the autopublish package I can see the publication. So I know the problem is here

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you're passing any options through for the `ops` argument of your publication, and you're then checking that the `ops` argument isn't empty before proceeding, try either passing in the correct options or removing the check.